# IPv6 socket creation failed: Address family not supported by protocol

Tags: debian, ipv6, exim, ipv4

*OS: GNU/Linux Debian 9.2 64-bit*

I [disabled IPv6](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/402218/126755) on one of my servers.

And now I'm getting this in `mail`:

```
exim paniclog
...
```

> ```
> IPv6 socket creation failed: Address family not supported by protocol
> ```

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of, man needs to disable IPv6 in `exim4`.

In the following file:

```
/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf
```

Make sure this line is there, if not, add it, or change it:

```
disable_ipv6='true'
```

But I tried only this solution and the mail is still coming, so digging further...

In the same file, make sure this line is set to `true`:

```
dc_minimaldns='true'
```

Now edit this file:

```
/etc/hosts
```

Let's suppose, this line defines your server name:

```
127.0.1.1   server-name
```

Change it as follows:

```
127.0.1.1   server-name.localhost server-name
```

Now, verify, that this command:

```
hostname --fqdn
```

Returns:

```
server-name.localhost
```

If so, you can update your Exim4 configuration:

```
update-exim4.conf
```

And restart the Exim4 service:

```
systemctl restart exim4.service
```